# Flexible layout with fixed width sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

I need to a create a flexible layout similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/Lu9gQ/12/

With these following properties:

- header as in the example
- the "left" must have: width = ( 100% - #sidebar's width ), and height = ( 100% - #header's height )
- the "sidebar" must have a fixed width and height = ( 100% - #header's height )
- the layout must be flexible only if the window'width is greater than a fixed width

  ```
  Is there any way to do it?
  ```

Comment: I don't think this can be done using only css, If I were to do this I would do it using js/jquery to dynamically change properties as the window changes size.

Comment: I don't need a pure css solution, also using js and jquery it will be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a solution to this using jquery and some js to manage the window resizing dynamically. Basically the function `conflayout()` manages the setup and this is basically called every time the window is resized and also once at the beginning to set the original.

To change the set size at which the design becomes fluid, change 800 in :

`if (window.innerWidth > 800) {`

to whatever number you like.

when the width of the screen becomes smaller than that number a div is wrapped around the contents of `body` which acts as a wrapper that remains static.

Live Example:

http://thepelican.me/liquidcssexample.html

---

The js:

```
var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
  var timers = {};
  return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
    if (!uniqueId) {
      uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
    }
    if (timers[uniqueId]) {
      clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
    }
    timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

$(window).resize(function () {
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){

conflayout()

      //...
    }, 1, "reloadproperties");
});

function conflayout() {

if (window.innerWidth > 800) {

$('#left').width((window.innerWidth-$('#sidebar').width())+1) 
$('#left, #sidebar').css({minHeight: window.innerHeight-$('#header').height()}) 
 $("#wrapper").unwrap();
 $('#wrapper').css({width: 'auto !important'});

}
else
{
    if($('#contain').size() < 1) {
    $('body').wrapInner('<div id="contain" />');
    }
    $('#wrapper').css({width: '800px !important'});
    $('#contain').css({width: '800px',position: 'fixed', height: '100%' })
}

}

$(document).ready(function() { 
conflayout()
});
```

Comment: this is pretty much what I was looking for, but I have two questions:

- both #left and #sidebar are 35px higher than necessary, which is #header's height, how could I fix it?

- both #left and #sidebar's height will not be modified based on their content, in other words if there's a 100x10000 element inside #left it will go outside, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: no worries, if you find anymore issues be sure to let me know as I would like to make this as usable as possible c:

Comment: thank you again for your code, is there a way to do something like this: if ( #left's height > 100% ) { #sidebar's height = #left's height; } ? So that #sidebar and #left will always have the same height

Answer (score 0):

replace your css with this

```
body{
margin:0px
}
#wrapper {
width:100%;
min-width:500px;
height:auto;
overlay:hidden;
}
#header {
height:5%;
width:100%;        
background-color:yellow;
}
#content {
width:100%;
height: auto;
min-height:500px;
}
#left {
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 90%;
position: absolute;
width: 95%;
background-color:blue;
}
#sidebar {
min-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 5%;
width: 100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

​
I don't know if is this that you need